# Append to number list

Tags: prolog

```
numbers([],[]).
numbers([H|T],L):- ((H @>=10 , H @=<15) -> append(H,LI,L);true),numbers(T,LI).
```

I am having problem there... All H should be added at L list... but i cant achieve that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` won't work on an unbound `LI`. Try moving `numbers(T, LI)` first or remove `append` altogether by saying

```
((H @>=10 , H @=<15) -> L = [H|LI]; L = LI)
```

Comment: hm i am not getting results...
numbers([H|T],L):- ((H @>=10 , H @=<15) -> LI=[H|L];LI=L),numbers(T,LI).

Comment: Sorry, swapped `L`/`LI` by mistake. Corrected the answer.

Comment: I hope if this _is_ homework, you'll actually take time to understand what's going on ;)

Comment: it isnt exactly for HW. I think that i have understand it.also i had to put numbers([],[])